# Set value for key in case of NSInteger

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, setvalue

I am trying to set a value in core data using `setValue:forKey:` but it is throwing an error:

> (Use of undeclared identifier: 'newID'}

when trying to save an NSInteger. Can anyone suggest the correct syntax?

```
 NSInteger newID = lastID+1;
 [record setValue:newID forKey:@"localid"];//error
```

Got similar error when I tried `setObject` instead of `setValue`

Comment: You should be getting an error about trying to pass an `NSInteger` to a method that expects an `id`. You can't pass an `NSInteger` value to `setObject:forKey:` or to `setValue:forKey:`.

Comment: Convert your `NSInteger` (primitive data type) to `NSNumber` (object) and then call `setObject:forKey:`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSInteger` is a primitive type, not an object. You should box it into an `NSNumber` like this:

```
NSInteger newID = lastID+1;
 [record setValue:@(newID) forKey:@"localid"];
```

And you can convert back like this:

```
NSInteger recordId = [((NSNumber*)[record valueForKey:@"localid"]) integerValue]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only set NSObject. Simplest way is

```
record [@"localid"] = @(newID);
```

And you should avoid setValue:forKey: and valueForKey: and either use setObject: and objectForKey: or the modern syntax - unless you have a good reason why you'd want the "value" methods.

Comment: The value calls are part of KVC and the contract with `NSManagedObject`.  The OP should **not** be using `-setObject: forKey:` as those are part of `NSDictionary`, not `NSManagedObject`.